# How to create an Azure break-glass account without mobile password reset configured?

Tags: azure

I'm trying to set up a "break-glass" global administrator account within the Azure portal for use in a high-level emergency.

I have an account created but when I try to login to test it, I see this screen:

[image]

Pressing Cancel doesn't skip the step, it just reloads the password page followed by this same screen.

The problem is that I don't want this account to be tied to a particular phone or email address due to the very nature of it.  While I can easily set up an email distribution list to deal with the second issue, there is no phone number to use here as the company doesn't have a sole phone for this purpose.

Reading [Microsoft's documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-emergency-access), there appears to be some contradiction as the document states that the account should be excluded from the usual sign-in policies, but the workarounds (e.g. [custom controls](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/controls)) cannot actually be used for self-service password reset).

Can anyone recommend a better approach please?

Comment: If the downvoter would care to offer some reason that would be a lot more helpful...

Comment: Not sure who and why the downvote was received, but I think you can simply skip this step. So just press cancel and it should continue.

Comment: Thank you.  Sadly pressing Cancel doesn't bypass this screen - it just loops back to the same screen.

Comment: The question doesn't look like a practical, detailed question for this community. Please bear in mind that this community has an insanely broad scope, it's pointed to power users, and Azure itself is a brand encompassing an extensive set of services. If this question corresponds to a professional setting, it might be better suited for [webmasters.se], [sf], [devops.se], among other [se] sites. Please post a question in [meta] for a site recommendation.